# (Pico) USB serial connection having noise?

Tags: usb, uart, pi-pico, serial-console

I'm having some trouble trying to make a simple USB IO demo to test the Pico. Apparently, the USB serial connection seems to be noisy, and always puts something into the UART buffer even though I am not sending anything from my end.
In the following code, I simply try to read something with getchar_timeout, which should return PICO_ERROR_TIMEOUT if nothing was sent through serial, but it's instead just printing random characters (even ilegible ones). What could be the cause of this?

```
int main() {
    stdio_init_all();
    char PC_input;
    
    while (1) {
        sleep_ms(1000);
        PC_input = getchar_timeout_us(1000);

        if (PC_input == PICO_ERROR_TIMEOUT) {
            printf("Timeour error!\n");
        } else {
            printf("input was %c\n", PC_input);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output I get looks like this (I only typed in 'asd123'):
input was �
input was �
input was a
input was s
input was d
input was 1
input was 2
input was 3
input was �
input was �
input was �
input was �

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the baud rate in your serial terminal is set to 115200. Also, try a different cable, and if that fails, try a different computer.

Comment: Yep, I'm calling minicom with   
`minicom -b 115200 -o -D /dev/ttyACM0 `
And the cable works fine, since it's reading and transmitting just fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Fixed!
The problem was that I was storing the return of the getchar_timeout_us function as a char instead of int.